# ASP.Net Identity automatically logs users into my test site if they've been on the live site even though different versions use different databases

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have built an ASP.NET MVC web application which uses ASP.NET Identity for authentication.

I have published the site to a dev web address and a test web address. If I log in to the dev site then then browse to the test site it automatically logs me in. This is an error however as the different versions of the site use different user tables and therefore it comes into trouble when it searches for the userId of the authenticated user as it cannot find it.

I can get around this for now by logging out of the dev site first and then logging into the test site. This won't be an option in the future however as some clients will have access to a preview version of the site and the live site, therefore I need to log them out when they are incorrectly logged in because they've logged into a different version.

Is there anyway I can stop this error occurring?

Comment: You'd usually do that through subdomains. Someone logged in to `dev.something.com` will not be logged in `www.something.com`. Try looking at the scope of the login cookies involved. It should also be possible to make sure the same cookie doesn't allow you to access both the sites, but that will mean logging to one will effectively log you out of the other, which you probably don't want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you are using `OWIN` authentication pipeline with `ASP.NET Identity`
when configuring authentication you should use something like

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName = ".AspNet.Cookies"
    });
```

`CookieName` must be different. Or alternatively you can explicitly define `CookiePath` or `CookieDomain` to show exactly the path or domain of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in your configuration you have something like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    CookieName = <read from config>
});
```

CookieAuthenticationOptions has a string property called CookieName which is what you can use to change the name of the cookie. You can put the actual cookie name in the config and read it from there on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the authentication cookie name. You can do this in the web.config of the site

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".{{YOURCOOKIE_NAME}}" loginUrl="~/Account/SignIn" />
</authentication>
```

Just change `{{YOURCOOKIE_NAME}}` with the desired name. So if you have different cookie names in DEV and TEST it should resolve your issue.